# How to make embedded Jpanel go to WEST

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

Im creating an application in java swing and in it Im making what I think is called an embedded Jpanel which is to my understanding a jpanel inside a jpanel. To make this simpler we will use the panel names there is content, sidebar, and content sidebar

Sidebar is just the sidebar for the application with buttons

Content is the main content of the app

Content sidebar is a side bar inside of content, I use this so my settings page has its own side bar apart from the normal side bar.

I make sidebar aligned to WEST and content CENTER

after `content.add(contentSidebar, BorderLayout.WEST);` it won't make content sidebar go to west and im not sure why.

this is my source code

```
package Assets.Settings;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Security implements ActionListener{
    JFrame Security;
    JPanel sideBar;
    JPanel content;

    //for sidebar
    JButton volume;
    JButton security;
    JButton contactUs;

    JPanel contentSidePanel;
//    JButton twoStep;
//    JButton changePassword;


    public void security(){
        Security = new JFrame();
        sideBar = new JPanel();
        content = new JPanel();

        contentSidePanel = new JPanel();

        sideBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 700));
        content.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 700));

        content.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        Security.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Security.setTitle("Anonyomail Security Settings");
        Security.setSize(1152, 700);
        Security.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

        contentSidePanel.setLayout( new java.awt.BorderLayout());

        volume = new JButton();
        security = new JButton();
        contactUs = new JButton();

//        twoStep = new JButton();
//        changePassword = new JButton();

        volume.addActionListener(this);
        contactUs.addActionListener(this);

        volume.setText("Volume");
        security.setText("Security");
        contactUs.setText("Contact Us");

//        changePassword.setText("Change Password");
//        twoStep.setText("2-Step");

        security.setBackground(Color.decode("#24a0ed"));

        



        contentSidePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 700));

        contentSidePanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

//        contentSidePanel.add(changePassword);
//        contentSidePanel.add(twoStep);

        content.add(contentSidePanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

        sideBar.add(volume);
        sideBar.add(security);
        sideBar.add(contactUs);


        Security.add(sideBar, BorderLayout.WEST);
        Security.add(content, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        Security.pack();
        Security.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == volume){
            //open volume
        }else if(e.getSource() == contactUs){
            //open contact us
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

The issue is that I didn't give content a border layout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call `content.add(contentSidePanel, BorderLayout.WEST)` however you never set `content`'s layout manager to `BorderLayout`. I believe `JPanel`'s default layout manager is `FlowLayout` and thus `BorderLayout.WEST` implies nothing.

On another note, it seems like you're only adding one thing, `contentSidePanel`, to `content`. I believe that `BorderLayout` will size `content` to the same size as `contentSidePanel` and that specifying `BorderLayout.WEST` will have no effect since there is nothing in the center or to the east. Try adding a test `JPanel` to `content` and setting it's layout to `BorderLayout.CENTER` to see if I'm correct.

**Note:** `BorderLayout`'s position constants where updated in JDK 1.4 from compass positions (`NORTH`, `EAST`, ...) to wordier constants (`PAGE_START`, `PAGE_END`, `LINE_START`, `LINE_END` and `CENTER`). Therefor the use of `BorderLayout.WEST` should be replaced with `BorderLayout.LINE_START`. - from [How to use BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)

Comment: Yes you were correct the issue is that I never set a layout for content

Comment: *"wordier constants (PAGE_.., LINE_.."* These are internationalized or localized. For a RTL locale, (e.g. Arabic), the `LINE` constants will be reversed.